# Red box around chapters in table of contents and references in pdf document

Tags: hyperref

I would like to know how I can remove these red boxes that appeared in my document after inserting `\hyperref`.

[image]

Boa tarde. Gostaria de saber como posso retirar estas caixas em vermelho que apareceram no meu documento, após inserir o \hyperref.

Comment: `\hypersetup{colorlinks}`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica. Ajudou bastante e consegui deixar todos os meus links com a mesma cor do texto.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. It is in your best interest to post your questions in English.

Comment: Posso postar sim em inglês.

Comment: `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` to hide the markup of links.

Answer (score 6):

You can remove the boxes (not every PDF viewer draws them) by adding

```
\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0}
```

Example

```latex
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Title}

\section{Title}

Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]